# ESP32 Dev board NPN Circuit

Tags: esp32

Can someone please explain how the marked part of the circuit works.

[image]

This is the original schematic from Espressif for the ESP32 dev. board.

source: https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/ESP32-Core-Board-V2_sch.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESP32 Dev Board DTR/RTS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/473443/esp32-dev-board-dtr-rts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it easier to understand, redraw the circuit as follows and include two pull-up resistors from the right corner of the picture.

[image: schematic]

Now you can see, that when DTR is high, EN pin will be the same as RTS signal (passing through Q1), while IO0 pin will be high (due to R7 pull-up) regardless of RTS.

When DTR is low, EN pin will be high (due to R11 pull-up) regardless of RTS, while IO0 will have inverted RTS signal (inverted by Q2).